# ASP.NET hosted on Centos7 with Windows authentication - GSSAPI: Feature not available

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, kerberos, kestrel-http-server

We have ASP.NET backend server running on .NET 5, its hosted on Centos7 and we have some issues with Windows AD authentication.

We have followed this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#kestrel, meaning that we have added `AddAuthentication` + `AddNegotiate` and `UseAuthentication` to our `Startup.cs`, host machine - Centos7 is in domain, we have also set the `KRB5_KTNAME`, it points to the existing keytab file, which we have generated on the domain controller.

When i use command `kinit username@DOMAIN.COMPANY.COM` and then fill out my password, everything seems to be ok, i also see some ticket, when i invoke `klist` command.

But for some reason, our ASP.NET server is unable to authenticate me, when i open its url in a browser, fill out my credentials, i get the following error:
`2021-06-21 07:51:55.4321|ERROR|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateHandler|An exception occurred while processing the authentication request. Interop+NetSecurityNative+GssApiException: GSSAPI operation failed with error - Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (Feature not available).`

I have completely no idea what this error means and i am unable to google any meaningful results, do you have any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: Didn't know that CentOS7 could host .Net 5.

Comment: Are you browse the website using name or ip address? I have the same error if using ip address, if change to hostname, e.g. http://mywebserver:5000, the error just gone & authenticated.